# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65488 bytes) In Magento 1.9.1

Tags: magento, fatal-error

I have change my unsecure base url from `{{base_url}}` to `{{unsecure_base_url}}`.
After this I am getting this error
 `"Fatal error:Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65488 bytes)"`.

I have tried `ti change set ini_set('memory_limit', '512M')`.

Now it show the error `"Fatal error:Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65488 bytes)"`.
I also changed the values in databse  `core_config_data > unsecure/base_url” andchange` the value to `“{{base_url}}”`;but still have the same error. Can anyone help me?. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your changes will do something after clearing cache. You can delete files in

```
{Magento dir}/var/cache
```

The fact that setting the limit to 512M does not help, is that it needs even more (sounds like a leak to me). Usually something is wrong, but you could try to increase memory usage until you reach a sane number.

The official documentation states a minimum of 254 and a required 512 megabyte of ram. Maybe the usage may increase when modules/plugins are added, custom layouts are used, etc.

http://magento.com/resources/previous-magento-system-requirements

Comment: Thanks.it works fine after deleting {Magento dir}/var/cache files.thanks a lot